# Set default image after click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want just when I click on the image I see the new image and just after the click I want the new image changes with the default one, but I have to drag the mouse to see the default image but I don't want that.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img-button").live('click', function () {
           $(this).attr("src","images/pressed.svg");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: FYI: live is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+

Comment: So when you click on the image it changes to a different image. You than want the image to change back to the original source when you move the mouse?

Comment: no epascarello, I want to see the new image only in the click action and then it disappears and the default image replaces the new.

Comment: Could you post your HTML Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have one image, I suggest you give it an ID instead of (ab)using the classname.
If you have several and use the same image for all, then change $("#myImage") below to $(".img-button")

Toggle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myImage").toggle(
     function() {
       $(this).attr('src','images/pressed.jpg');
     },
     function() {
       $(this).attr('src',"images/default.jpg");
    });
});
```

Swap after leaving

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myImage').on("click",function() {
       $(this).attr('src','images/pressed.jpg');
    });
    $('#myImage').on("mouseleave",function() {
       $(this).attr('src',"images/default.jpg");
    });
});
```

Swap half a sec after pressing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myImage').on("click",function() {
       $(this).attr('src','images/pressed.jpg');
       setTimeout(function() {
         $('#myImage').attr('src',"images/default.jpg");
       },500);
    });
});
```

Comment: setTimeout not working for me, I have all time the pressed image.

Comment: Try mouseup instead of click with the timeout

Comment: Or if you want to change back even if they keep holding the mouse, try mousedown